# Using a check constraint to ensure that a varchar includes letters and numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql, check-constraints

I am trying to create a check constraint to ensure that a stored varchar has atleast 1 letter and 1 number and am not sure exactly how to do this.  Any help would be appreciated.

This is what I have so far:

```
CHECK (VALUE LIKE [a-z] AND LIKE [0-9])
```

will this work?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you, please, show us what you have tried?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html

Comment: Please take a look at [the stack overflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for advice on how to ask better questions to avoid downvotes, your questions being ignored, etc, and to help you get better answers.

Answer (score 2):

That syntax is invalid, so it can never work. At minimum you'd need to quote the pattern values in the `LIKE` expressions. They must also have wildcards so they aren't anchored; at the moment, your expression tries to say "value must be a single character that is a letter, and a single character that is a number". Which is impossible. Additionally, you can't use character classes `([...])` in `LIKE`.

What you want is to use a pair of simple regular expressions instead. This:

```
CHECK (thevalue ~ '[[:alpha:]]' AND thevalue ~ '\d')`
```

would do.

You can play some simple games with the expression to force this into a single regular expression, but I don't think there's much point, it'll just be harder to read and uglier.

All that said, I'm worried that you might be attempting to *validate password strength*. If you are doing that then this is absolutely the wrong way to go about it. Do *not* use a `CHECK` constraint - you won't be able to introduce stronger requirements later until all existing rows pass the constraint. Do the check as input validation in your application instead, and use *proper password strength checking tools* - which already exist - instead of rolling your own.

Comment: Last but not least, OP should read the bloody manual a bit. :-|

Comment: Definitely the answer, but technically `\w` is an alias of `[[:alnum:]_]`. `[[:alpha:]]` or `[A-Za-z]` would do the work.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look [at the manual on constraints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html) and [the w3resource page on the PostgreSQL CHECK constraint](http://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/check.php).

Comment: Link-only answers are generally not preferred on Stack Overflow - links change and go away, and they don't tell the reader anything much when they're browsing a list of answers. Try to provide a little explanation and a link for more detail.

Comment: @CraigRinger thanks for your suggestion. My answer pointed to the question before editing the question where no code shared by user.  So i just pointed user to the related topic !